# plotting lat-lon climate data, alternative to geom_tile()?

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, world-map

I have the following [data.frame](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/b9b0mvcykdnbs9th0g64a/test.csv?rlkey=5nn6mxw4k4hdi49vfdnn732ni&dl=0) with three columns: value of a given variable, longitude and latitude.

I can plot the `data.frame` as follows:

```
library(ggplot2)

df=read.csv("test.csv")
    
plot_df = ggplot() +
  geom_tile(data=df, aes(x=lon,y=lat,fill=value))

print(plot_df)
```

[image: figure]

The plot is fine, but I would like to find another `ggplot2` function that does not treat each gridpoint as a tile and gives a more homogeneous pattern as result, like the following figure:

[image: figure2]

I bet there are many options, but it is important for me to keep the same `data.frame` format as input data, i.e. with 3 columns: value, lon, lat.